# Decomposition of sorting permutation in fewest amount of transpositions

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, permutations

I found that any permutation cycle of length n can be written as a product of n-1 two-level permutations or transpositions. However, there are many other ways to do this decomposition(but it has to remain even/odd).

Is there an algorithm or method to find the transposition decomposition with the fewest amount of transpositions? (I found this is called a 'God's algorithm')

I also found dozens of sorting algorithms in my search, but it seems they are made to optimize computational time which comprises to the most extent the amount of equations of numbers. Here, I assume this can be seen instantly, but swapping two levels is a physical thing and takes a lot of effort.

Comment: See http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4096/minimum-number-of-transpositions-to-sort-a-list.

Comment: @lhf I don't have sufficient reputation to comment at the first answer there, which could be what I'm looking for, but what I'm missing is a source or at least a short explanation/proof why that is indeed the smallest amount of transpositions possible.